# SQL Server select and update

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
Id EmployeeId Salary Date
1  11         100    2022-12-01
2  11         111    2023-01-01
3  11         NULL   2023-02-01
4  22         200    2023-02-01 
5  22         222    2023-03-01
6  22         NULL   2023-04-01
```

I receive a list of Ids as input - 2, 5.
I need to find all rows that have same EmployeeId as rows 2, 5 and have Date > date of rows 2,5. Then I need to set their salary equal to rows 2, 5.

Result:

```
Id EmployeeId Salary Date
1  11         100    2022-12-01
2  11         111    2023-01-01
3  11         111    2023-02-01
4  22         200    2023-02-01 
5  22         222    2023-03-01
6  22         222    2023-04-01
```

I tried to do it with update, set and subqueries, but I've spent whole evening with no result.
I'm new to SQL, please help me out.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to approach this, one way would be to use `apply` and a correlated query to select the values to populate and then using a table expression, update the missing values from the applied query:

```
with u as (
  select *
  from t
  outer apply (
    select t2.Salary LatestSalary
    from t t2
    where t2.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId 
      and t2.Id in (2,5) 
      and t.Date > t2.Date 
      and t.Salary is null
  )x
)
update u set salary = LatestSalary
where LatestSalary is not null;
```

See a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8sDKjBeH)

Comment: Thank you for fast reply! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with c as (
    select 
             Id
            ,EmployeeId
            ,Salary,Date_, 
            LAG(Salary) over (partition by EmployeeId order by Date_) as sal
    from rr
)
update c
set Salary=sal
where Salary is null -- id in(6,3)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wq1mRU5j)

Comment: Elegant code. In my case there could be anything in Salary, not just NULLs. I tried your solution without `case`, just lag, and it does not work as I expected. But thank you, now I know what LAG is in sql.

Comment: your welcome, I deleted Case, for your example is working, only if the rights are null, you need to check, or you can put the Id that needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
update T
set salary = (
    select Salary from T T2
    where t2.Id in (2, 5)
        and t2.EmployeeId = T.EmployeeId
        and t2.Date > T.Date
)
where Salary is null;
```